# Getting max record on varchar field

Tags: mysql, sql, join, max

I have this query

```
SELECT 
s.account_number,
a.id AS 'ASPIRION ID',
a.patient_first_name,
a.patient_last_name,
s.admission_date,
s.total_charge,
astat.name AS 'STATUS',
astat.definition,
latest_note.content AS 'LAST NOTE',
a.insurance_company
FROM
accounts a
    INNER JOIN
services s ON a.id = s.account_id
    INNER JOIN
facilities f ON f.id = a.facility_id
    INNER JOIN
account_statuses astat ON astat.id = a.account_status_id
    INNER JOIN
(SELECT 
    account_id, MAX(content) content, MAX(created)
FROM
    notes
GROUP BY account_id) latest_note ON latest_note.account_id = a.id
WHERE
    a.facility_id = 56
```

My problem comes from

```
(SELECT 
    account_id, MAX(content) content, MAX(created)
FROM
    notes
GROUP BY account_id)
```

**Content** is a varchar field and I am needed to get the most recent record. I now understand that MAX will not work on a varchar field the way that I want it. I am not sure how to be able to  get the corresponding content with the **MAX** **id** and **group that by account id** on in this join.

What would be the best way to do this?
My notes table looks like this...

```
id  account_id  content         created 
1   1           This is a test  2011-03-16 02:06:40 
2   1           More test       2012-03-16 02:06:40
```

Comment: do you have a column that corresponds to `created` in any of the other tables?

Comment: What in your table defines "most recent"? Do you have a datetime column you can use? You might want to take a peek at this article so we can help. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: How does `content` look like?

Comment: I do have a created column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are two choices.  If your `content` is not very long and don't have funky characters, you can use the `substring_index()`/`group_concat()` trick:

```
(SELECT account_id,
        SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(content ORDER BY created desc SEPARATOR '|' 
                                    ), 1, '|') as content
 FROM notes
 GROUP BY account_id
) latest_note
ON latest_note.account_id = a.id
```

Given the names of the columns and tables, that is likely not to work.  Then you need an additional join or a correlated subquery in the `from` clause.  I think that might be easiest in this case:

```
select . . .,
       (select n.content
        from notes n
        where n.account_id = a.id
        order by created desc
        limit 1
       ) as latest_note
from . . .
```

The advantage to this method is that it only gets the notes for the rows you need.  And, you don't need a `left join` to keep all the rows.  For performance, you want an index on `notes(account_id, created)`.

Comment: Can you give the full statement? I'm not sure what you mean

Comment: @Rob: Remove the latest_row join completely and replace `latest_note.content AS 'LAST NOTE',` with the subquery `(select n.content ...) as "LAST NOTE"`.

Comment: I am rather new to sql. How do I create an index? I ran the query but it takes a very long time

Comment: @Rob: Simply google for CREATE INDEX and you'll find the syntax needed. This is something even a beginner should be able to accomplish without problems. :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
s.account_number,
a.id AS 'ASPIRION ID',
a.patient_first_name,
a.patient_last_name,
s.admission_date,
s.total_charge,
astat.name AS 'STATUS',
astat.definition,
latest_note.content AS 'LAST NOTE',
a.insurance_company
FROM
accounts a
INNER JOIN services s ON a.id = s.account_id
INNER JOIN facilities f ON f.id = a.facility_id
INNER JOIN account_statuses astat ON astat.id = a.account_status_id
INNER JOIN
(SELECT account_id, MAX(created) mxcreated
 FROM notes GROUP BY account_id) latest_note ON latest_note.account_id = a.id and   
 latest_note.mxcreated = --datetime column from any of the other tables being used
WHERE a.facility_id = 56
```

You have to `join` on the `max(created)` which would give the latest content.

Or you can change the query to

```
SELECT account_id, content, MAX(created) mxcreated
FROM notes GROUP BY account_id
```

as `mysql` allows you even if you don't include all non-aggregated columns in `group by` clause. However, unless you `join` on the max date you wouldn't get the correct results.

Comment: The ` SELECT account_id, content, MAX(created) mxcreated
FROM notes GROUP BY account_id` still does not give the corresponding content to the max created

Answer (score 0):

The last created record is the one for which does *not exist* a newer one. Hence:

```
SELECT 
  s.account_number,
  a.id AS "ASPIRION ID",
  a.patient_first_name,
  a.patient_last_name,
  s.admission_date,
  s.total_charge,
  astat.name AS "STATUS",
  astat.definition,
  latest_note.content AS "LAST NOTE",
  a.insurance_company
FROM accounts a
INNER JOIN services s ON a.id = s.account_id
INNER JOIN facilities f ON f.id = a.facility_id
INNER JOIN account_statuses astat ON astat.id = a.account_status_id
INNER JOIN
(
  SELECT account_id, content
  FROM notes
  WHERE NOT EXISTS 
  (
    SELECT *
    FROM notes newer
    WHERE newer.account_id = notes.account_id
    AND newer.created > notes.created
  )
) latest_note ON latest_note.account_id = a.id
WHERE a.facility_id = 56;
```

Comment: This returns duplicates of the same account for some reason

Comment: You are saying that when you remove the latest_note part from the query completely, then you get less records? Please double check. This would only be possible when you have two records in `notes` for the same `account_id` with exactly the same `created`.

Comment: BTW: Gordon's suggestion to use a subquery in your select clause rather than joining a derived table, should be the simplest solution when you are only interested in one column of the table (`content` in your case).